# How to directly specify some values as an argument in C++ instead of specifying an array name or a pointer to an array

Tags: c++

Can I write a function in C++ to accept an array of values like this:

```cpp
void someFunction(/*the parameter for array*/){
    //do something
}

someFunction({ 1, 2, 3 });
```

Comment: You could use `std::vector<int>` as parameter type.

Comment: `std::initializer_list<int>` could be an option.

Comment: @felix Yes, just so long as the parameters are always known at compile time

Comment: `template <std::size_t N> void SomeFunction(const int (&values[N])` or `template<std::size_t N> void SomeFunction(const std::array<int,N>& values)` can also be used. (remove the const if you want to be able to change the content of the array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various ways of doing this.

##### Method 1

Using `initializer_list` as parameter type.

```
void someFunction(std::initializer_list<int> init){
   
}
int main()
{
    
   someFunction({ 1, 2, 3 });
}
```

##### Method 2

Using `std::vector<int>` as parameter type.

```
void someFunction(const std::vector<int> &init){
   
}
int main()
{
    
   someFunction({ 1, 2, 3 });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could get inspiration from e.g. [`std::min`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min) and use [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list)

```
void someFunction(std::initializer_list<int> ints) {
    for (int i : ints)
    {
        std::cout << i << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.
One option is to use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), and in your specific case `std::vector<int> const&` for the parameter of `someFunction`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void someFunction(std::vector<int> const & a) 
{
    for (int i : a)
    {
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    someFunction({ 1, 2, 3 });
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
1, 2, 3,
```